# Plesk Migration without Migration Manager

Tags: migration, plesk

I've got a problem to migrate A user from one server to another.

I tried to use the migration manager, but if I start the migration manager the migration will be started but after 2 seconds it has finished and no migration has be doen.

What can I do? Is there anything I can do?

or should I moove the data manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem. I had to increase the number of free domains!.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Plesk Mass Transfer Script. 
The Plesk Mass Transfer Script (formerly Mass Migration Script) is designed to allow providers transferring accounts from one Plesk farm to another one by an automated way.

The script will create migration sessions for each domain only if you run mmigration.php with '--per-domain' option. By default single migration session is created.

More details and scenarios you can find here http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/113283